# Powershell Regular Expression?

Tags: regex, powershell, special-characters

So i have a log files that contains list of file that was copied from 1 folder to another folder.

For example,

12 Aug 17:23:51 C:\Users\Folder_1\File1.exe move to D:\Users\Folder_1\File1.exe
12 Aug 17:24:33 C:\Users\Folder_2\File2.xml move to D:\Users\Folder_1\File2.xml

so i wanted to to extract the 2 paths in the above line and write out into another text file.

For example,

C:\Users\Folder_1\File1.exe      D:\Users\Folder_1\File1.exe

I'm not sure how do i write the regular expression here. What i wanted to achieve in the regex pattern is say C Drive, ignore the length of the path, and exe files only.
Tried something like "(C:\)(.exe)" , doesn't work.

I would appreciate also if any1 can provide me with a list of special characters for regex and their uses. For example /d means decimal /D not Decimal etc. I still can't quite figure out what /< /> /b ? ! character means though i still saw post of people using it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this `regex` will help you

```
[CD]:\\.+?.exe
```

and as far as the notations are concerned I am quoting some of them

- [abc]    A single character of: a, b, or c
- [^abc]   Any single character except: a, b, or c
- [a-z]    Any single character in the range a-z
- [a-zA-Z] Any single character in the range a-z or A-Z
- ^    Start of line
- $    End of line
- \A   Start of string
- \z   End of string 
  -. Any single character
- \s   Any whitespace character
- \S   Any non-whitespace character
- \d   Any digit
- \D   Any non-digit
- \w   Any word character (letter, number,underscore)
- \W   Any non-word character
- \b   Any word boundary
- (...) Capture everything enclosed
- (a|b)   a or b
- a?   Zero or one of a
- a*   Zero or more of a
- a+   One or more of a
- a{3} Exactly 3 of a
- a{3,} 3 or more of a
- a{3,6} Between 3 and 6 of a

for more `regex` help try this [tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

Comment: Fantastic! This surely clears up alot for me especially with all the examples from the site! 1 more quick question tho. Do you have any idea the uses of > < in regular expression context? Found it from here http://www.zerrouki.com/powershell-cheatsheet-regular-expressions/  but its pretty much meaningless to me without any appropriate examples.

Comment: @Jack-V `\<` `\>` these are used to check something for begning and ending of words I would rather suggest you to use `\b` followed by whatever you want to match for word boundaries.

Comment: I can't seem to really comprehend the use of /b from the example given. Can you give me another example of use for it? Thanks